# PHP, dynamic form, access POST variables, checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, checkbox

I am trying to make dynamic form which will allow person to add multiple tooth data to the database. The problem I have is that after submitting the form I can't access the given variables and arrays (checkboxes) have only 1 value (first one).

[image]

To generate form I'm using jQuery, data about teeths are checkboxes.

Code to generate dynamic part of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add_row()
    {
        $rowno=$("#teeth_table tr").length;
        $rowno=$rowno+1;
        $("#teeth_table tr:last").after("<tr id='row"+$rowno+"'>" +
            "<td style='margin-left: 15px'> Quarter <input type='number' name='quarter[]' min='1' max='4' placeholder='1-4'></td>" +
            "<td style='margin-left: 15px'> Tooth number <input type='number' name='number[]' min='1' max='8' placeholder='1-8'></td>" +
            "<td style='margin-left: 15px'> Description <input type='text' name='desc[]'></td>" +
            "<td style='margin-left: 15px'> Measurement <input type='text' name='measure[]'></td>" +
            "<td style='margin-left: 15px'><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row"+$rowno+"')></td></tr>");
    }
    function delete_row(rowno)
    {
        $('#'+rowno).remove();
    }
</script>
```

The form code:

```
echo("
    <div style='margin-left: 30px'>
            <hr>
            <h4>Procedure data</h4>
            <div id='form_div'>
                <div style='margin-left: 20px'>
                <form method='post' action='dental_chart.php'>
                    <p>VAT_client:
                        <input type='text' name='VAT_client' value='$VAT_client' disabled/></input>
                    </p><p>VAT_doctor:
                        <input type='text' name='VAT_doctor' value='$VAT_doctor' disabled/></input>
                    </p><p>Date: 
                        <input type='date' name='date' value='$date' disabled/></input>
                    </p><p>Procedure type:
                        <input type='text' name='type' value='$procedure' disabled/></input>
                    </p><p>Description: 
                        <input type='text' name='description' placeholder='describe procedure'/>
                    </p>
                </div>
        ");
        ?>
        <hr>
        <h4>Insert procedure charting data - gap per tooth</h4>
        <div style='margin-left: 20px'>
            <table id="teeth_table">
                <tr id="row1">
                    <td style="margin-left: 15px"> Quarter <input type='number' name='quarter[]' min="1" max="4"
                                                                  placeholder="1-4"></td>
                    <td style="margin-left: 15px"> Tooth number <input type='number' name='number[]' min="1" max="8"
                                                                       placeholder="1-8"></td>
                    <td style="margin-left: 15px"> Description <input type='text' name='desc[]'></td>
                    <td style="margin-left: 15px"> Measurement <input type='text' name='measure[]'></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD TOOTH">
        </div>

        <p></p>
        <hr>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_row" value="SUBMIT FORM">
        </div>
        </form>
```

And my php part to access the POST data if it's not empty:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $VAT_client_p = $_POST['VAT_client'];
    $VAT_doctor_p = $_POST['VAT_doctor'];
    $date_p = $_POST['date'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    # dental chart multiple data
    $quarter = $_POST['quarter'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $desc_tooth = $_POST['desc'];
    $measure = $_POST['measure'];


    echo("<p>VAT_client = ". $VAT_client_p .", VAT_doctor = ". $VAT_doctor_p.", date: ".$date_p ."</p>");


    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['quarter']);$i++)
    {
        if($quarter[$i]!="" && $number[$i]!="" )
        {
            echo("<p>". count($quarter)." </p>");
            echo("<p>". count($desc_tooth)." </p>");
            echo("<p>quarter = '$quarter[$i]', tooth number = '$number[$i]', tooth desc: '$desc_tooth[$i]'</p>");
        }
    }
}
```

At this moment I just want to access the variables after submitting and echo them, when this part will be working I will perform transaction to insert the data into database. I will be grateful for any suggestion or advice, I'm stuck at this point.

(the result from running form first image is that arrays have only one element and VAT_doctor, VAT_client etc. are empty)

Comment: I just tried your code. For me it is printing all the added rows aswell.

Comment: VAT_client and VAT_doctor are empty, because I cant set them in HTML. They are disabled and no value is in it. The array POST quarter can be accessed in the for loop and is working for me

Comment: @davidev how did you try this code? Could you explain to me briefly?

Comment: What error do you get? I used your code run it on my server. I can send the form and get the output after that. You print all the input

Comment: Those values I assign after entering the page, I provide them via GET method from previous page.
I didnt notice any errors, I will check it now(sorry, Its my first project in PHP)

Comment: No problem, I have posted an answer below to attach you my output.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it looks fine for me.

I will show your my output, so you can verify if that is the correct behaviour you want.

**Entering these values:**

[image]

**Will result in this output from your PHP:**

[image]

For me it does look correct. Can you verify and tell me what error you still get? Do you get the same output?

Comment: It is the output I desire. I will check errors and put them here. I think that what causes the code not to work is that I have in form checkboxes and normal variables, as Im trying to submit it all together POST might not accept single variables and arrays(checkboxes). What do you think?

Comment: You mean in your echo $VAT_client ? You would need to make it like this echo "<form>" . $VAT_client . "... </form>"; Also make sure that this is .php file, so you can insert your variables from PHP.

Comment: I didnt get error messages yet(I dont know how to do this) but I found out that arrays from checkbos stops working(return only first element) when I try to transfer through post other variables(which are not part of the dynamic form)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by passing through post variables from dynamic form. Other variables I passed through GET method. I just managed to pass one more variable through post, I pass it as an array where the value is as first element and rest are empty elements.

```
    <form method='post' action='dental_chart.php?VAT_client=$VAT_client_g&VAT_doctor=$VAT_doctor_g&date=$date_g'>
    <p>Description:
        <input type='text' name='description[]' placeholder='describe procedure'/>
    </p>
    <hr>
<h4>Insert procedure charting data - gap per tooth:</h4>
<p></p>
<div style='margin-left: 20px'>
<table id='teeth_table'>
   <tr id='row1'>
       <td style='margin-left: 15px'> Quarter <input type='number' name='quarter[]' min='1' max='4' placeholder='1-4'></td>
       <td style='margin-left: 15px'> Tooth number <input type='number' name='number[]' min='1' max='8' placeholder='1-8'></td>
       <td style='margin-left: 15px'> Description <input type='text' name='desc[]'></td>
       <td style='margin-left: 15px'> Measurement <input type='text' name='measure[]'></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```